# How do I use Jsoup to log into a website and perform actions on an account Java

Tags: java, jsoup

I would like to make a program the will log into a website (Such as amazon) and then place an item into the shopping cart.

ATM I am trying to just log into the account. My current code is:

```
 Connection.Response initial = Jsoup
    .connect("http://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/authentication/login/en/authentication/login")
    .method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();

Connection.Response login = Jsoup
    .connect("http://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/authentication/login/en/authentication/login")
    .data("username","MYUSERNAME")
    .data("password","MYPASSWOR")
    .cookies(initial.cookies())
    .method(Method.POST)
    .execute();
```

I then get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=http://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/authentication/login/en/authentication/login
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:598)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:548)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:235)
at sneaker.Sneaker.main(Sneaker.java:98)
```

The website that I would like to log into is: http://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/authentication/login/
and the form action for the login is: 
http://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/authentication/login/en/authentication/login

What is not right?

Comment: Are you the same person who asked about a "sneakerbot" a while ago, or is there some bigger craze about creating programs to buy things off of amazon etc.? If you're the same person, it seems you've at least created a new username.

Comment: I see that [sneakerbots](http://www.highsnobiety.com/2016/04/27/sneaker-bots-how-do-they-work/) are a hot thing now. What a world we live in.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 403 Statuscode means `Forbidden`. Most probably the website wants to deny programmatic access like yours. Most of the time it's done with a weak check about the `User-Agent` HTTP header field. When you fake that, then it might work. But it is very clear that you violate the website owner's intention to deny programmatic access to his site.